# wipe ios build artifcats in react native clean project exit 65

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

When running either `xcodebuild clean`

or

using react-native-clean-project which includes a command along with the ios clean commands...

````
  ```'rm -rf ios/build && (killall Xcode || true) && xcrun -k && cd ios && xcodebuild -alltargets clean && cd .. && rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache" && rm -rf "$(getconf DARWIN_USER_CACHE_DIR)/org.llvm.clang.$(whoami)/ModuleCache" && rm -fr ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ && rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/',```
````

ios build errors with exit code 65 in azure devops or i'm unable to delete the build folder because it was not created by the build system? Is this a permission issue? I use the package above to clean or just regular xcodebuild clean.

````
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

error: Could not delete `/Users/me/repos/Mobile-App/ios/build` because it was not created by the build system.
    note: To mark this directory as deletable by the build system, run `xattr -w com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem true /Users/me/repos/Mobile-App/ios/build` when it is created.```


Looking for how to prevent this failure to clean the iOS build with react native.
````

Answer (score 0):

In my case, mostly **code 65** comes because

- `<your_app>/ios/build` still exists.

**Solution**

1. `rm -rf iod/build` and run again
2. Or you can just copy and paste `xattr -w com.apple.xcode.CreatedByBuildSystem true <your_app>/ios/build` command above the error message